# Yii2: получить идентификатор backend в frontend

Tags: php, yii2

Суть задачи: мне нужно получить идентификатор пользователя backend во frontend. 
Например, в фронтенд я могу узнать вошел пользователь или нет, написав так

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest
```

А возможно ли получить идентификатор, который укажет, вошел ли пользователь в backend?

Спасибо

Comment: шаблон yii2 advanced имеет 2 разные части - frontend и backend. можно сделать авторизацию в frontend и в backend. вот мне надо определять с frontend, прошел ли пользователь авторизацию во backend

Comment: понуал, вопросов нет

Comment: может кто то подскажет решение?